# Images on PHP pages on Linux OS disappears

Tags: php, linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, firefox

I'm trying to display image on my PHP pages, but Google Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu refuse to display the images. The same pages with the same images run pretty well in both browsers using Windows. Can any one explain to me what is happening ?

Comment: Please post the code you're using

Comment: it is basically a permission error in linux. you need to give permission recursively to the directory you are using

Comment: check your directory seperator and add your code too, let us know the folder permissions also.

Answer (score 0):

check to directory where your images are stored, make sure the permission is set to 777, or 775,

on your ubuntu terminal,
type in:

sudo chmod 777 /images_dir -R

Answer (score 0):

There are 1001 reasons that could cause this.

Most probable ones:

- Case problems on the file names. Many people developing systems in Windows and then porting in Linux face this problem. Remember that Linux is case sensitive. A file name a.png is different from A.png. On the other hand, windows is not case sensitive.
- Permission. Your files could have a permission problem. Try to open the files from the same directory the browser is trying to retrieve the files from. If you have problems in doing this, then Firefox will have the same problem (since it runs with your credentials).